# Animation states do not match character's behavior (Unity, C#)

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I am creating a simple endless runner game. The ground is made of different colliders. There are four states of animation:

1. Run,
2. Get force,
3. Jump,
4. Big jump.

Every state is looped and there are no exit times.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work well. The biggest problem is, when I press spacebar quickly, the character is in the state 0 (run animation) while in the air. Sometimes, also in the air, the character is able to get force. To me it seems, that even when the character is making jump it can touch another collider. However, my prevention methods don't work. How can I make those animation states match the character behavior?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour {

    public Animator animator;
    Rigidbody rigidBody;
    CapsuleCollider capsuleCollider;
    int isGrounded=2;
    int jumpType;
    float force = 2;
    float jump = 20000;
    float minJump = 0.1f;
    float jumpTime;
    bool isJumping;
    void Start () 
    {
        animator = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
        rigidBody=GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        capsuleCollider = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
    }

    void Update()
    {   
    if(isJumping)
    {
        jumpTime+=Time.deltaTime;
    }
        // if the character is grounded
        if (isGrounded==1)
        {
            //jump if the key is released, jump
            if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            {   isJumping=true;
                isGrounded=2;

                if(rigidBody.velocity.y<30)
                {
                    rigidBody.AddForce(Vector3.up*jump*force*0.55f);

                    jumpType=2;

                    if (force>2.5f) jumpType =3;
                    animator.SetInteger("state",jumpType);
                    force=2;
                }

            }
            //if the key is pressed, add force. longer you hold, higher you jump
            else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                animator.SetInteger("state",1);
                force+=Time.deltaTime*0.7f;
            }
            //just keep running 
            else if(rigidBody.velocity.y<0)
            {   
                animator.SetInteger("state",0); 
            }
        }

    }


    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {   
        //you are grounded. additional 'if', because sometimes you touch collider after jump        
        if(isJumping && isGrounded==2)
        {   if(jumpTime>minJump)
        {
            isGrounded=1;   
            isJumping=false;
            jumpTime=0;
        }}

    }

}
```

Comment: This should be an exam as you are... like... the 10th guy writing a runner game. The funny part is, you make the same mistakes at the very same place. Here's your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888210/how-to-apply-jump-both-to-controller-and-player-for-an-endless-runner-3d-in-unit

Comment: My problem is not lack of jump but lack of synchro with animation. The rest is fine.

Comment: Yup. Exactly. And there's a reason for that: Unity does what you tell it to do, not what you want it to do.

Comment: Thank you for the secret knowledge, sir. BTW Your link has nothing to do with my problem which was solved by reducing transition duration to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone cares, the problem was solved by reducing transition duration to 0. It can be done in the inspector.